# Change opacity of list items background png image

Tags: android, listview

I have this list adapter in order to have different images for background in my list View.

```
    int a=R.drawable.img1;
    int b=R.drawable.img2;
    private int[] backgr = new int[] {a,b};

    public list_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
         super(context, mylist, resource, from, to);

    }

  @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       int bPos = position % 2;
       view.setBackgroundResource(backgr[bPos]);

     return view;
    }
```

`img1` and `img2` are the same images with different opacity.

Could i use setAlpha here in order to have only one image and use alpha for the second?

Comment: Your question is a bit strange: "Could I use...".  Did you try it?  What was the result?  Try it first, then ask a question if you don't get the results you expect.

Comment: i have tried it with some ways but i dont get result...

Comment: So what exactly did you try and what results did you get?